# Is it possible to compare specific parts of a string in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, string, compare

I was wondering if it is possible to compare a specific part from a string with another string.
I would like to compare email adresses based on what is after the @ to find duplicates.

***For example:***

| email 1 | email 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ...@adressX | ...@adressZ |
| ...@adressY | ...@adressX |

So that I can then find and mark the duplicate adresses (in this case mark cells with @adressX in red for example) more quickly than with ctrl+f.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Is this a VBA question or formula question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `wildcard` matching like. Try below formula.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@",REPT(" ",100)),100))&"*",$B$2:$B$1000,0))
```

You can also use same formula for `Conditional Formatting`.

[image]